# How to get the position of another element in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My parent element has 2 child, the 2nd child can be dragged into the first child.

if it's dragged correctly (into the first child), a callback will be triggered.

how can I know if the drag ended in the correct location?

I'm using react-draggable.

Comment: keep some code what you tried before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar to what ( I think, if I understand your question correctly ) you are trying to do.
You can use `onStop` or `onDrag` method of `react-draggable` and get the data you want using the `DraggableEventHandler` parameter,

**OR** (using `ReactDOM` directly)

You can use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.someRef).getBoundingClientRect()`.
`someRef` should be the `ref` to your dragged component. Once you have your wanted `top` / `left` / `right` / `bottom` values, you can check if they are inside your other component (which position you will get in a similar way to `someRef`) inside the `onStop` or `onDrag` method of `react-draggable`.

Read about `getBoundingClientRect()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

There are probably more ways of doing what you are trying to, but the second method I wrote worked for me.